# Robotic Manipulator

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, machine-learning

I have started working on robotic manipulators and got into a project which deals with control of robotic manipulator using artificial neural networks (solution of inverse kinematics and trajectory generation, to be precise!).
Can someone please suggest me where to start as I have no prior knowledge about robotic manipulator and ANN and how to code them?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Akanshu Mahajan, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, and they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation and are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in Robotics Chat.

Comment: I will make sure to generalize questions in the future.Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: Thanks *Akanshu Mahajan* we try to strike a balance between trying to help answer peoples questions and having too many questions which will never help anyone else in the future. Once you you get started on your project, we would love to see some complex questions on these topics, they are just what we are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no prior experience in robotics, I would recommend one well known book, Craig - Introduction of Robotics: Mechanics and Control. This should explain well the basics of robotic manipulators.

For artificial intelligence (AI), I would recommend Russel, Norvig - Artificial Intelligence, a Modern Approach, although ANNs are not the central topic of the book, it is a very good and well known book on AI in general. It is always good to know what AI is about an what are the problem categories that can be solved with AI and what methods are recommended for the problem types.

There are scientific publications dealing explicitly with ANN for Inverse Kinematics,  e.g. this one:

Jha, Panchanand, and B. B. Biswal. "A Neural Network Approach for Inverse Kinematic of a SCARA Manipulator." IAES International Journal of Robotics and Automation (IJRA) 3.1 (2014): 52-61.

However trajectory generation is somewhat different in nature. I would recommend reading up generally on AI and machine learning to see which method is best suited for which class of problems.